# How to delete char from a column before a special character depending on the length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table having an ID column. I have some incorrect entries in the ID column. For ex:

a-ID
ab-ID
abc-ID

I need to update my ID column and remove everything before "-" only if the char are not more than 3, so if column value is abcd-ID, i don't want it to change.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tsql string functions:

```
update tablename
set id = right(id, len(id) - charindex('-', id))
where charindex('-', id) between 1 and 4
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53031289e0f884e415f725dc888e3dd3).